# NA generated for matched rows

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames A (var1,var2,var3,var4,var5) and B (var1,var2,var6) based on two common columns (var1 and var2) in a many-to-one relation.

I have tried merge and left_join, but I got NA in the column of var6 in the output even when I see there is a match. I do not see a pattern where NA appears.

```
merge(as.data.frame(A), as.data.frame(B), by=c("var1","var2"), all.x=TRUE)
```

Any idea? Is it possible that there is hidden space or something like that in var1 and var2? If so, how to check for that? Thanks!

Comment: please show a ssmall example

Comment: It could be possiblee that you have some leading/lagging spaces for those variables making it different in one dataset compared to another

Comment: How to check for leading/lagging spaces? var1 (var2) is generated in this way: as.numeric(A[,var5]-1) (as.numeric(A[,var5]+1)), and then add back to matrix A using cbind.

Comment: Just a simple option is `A[c('var1', 'var2')] <- lapply(A[c('var1', 'var2')], trimws)` and similarly for `B` and then try the `merge`